# Fixed size element has different width on one Chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a strange behavior on the browser of a client, I can't reproduce it on another computer.

I have a table with different width for each column, but on the client browser every column has the same width. What's strange is that it seems the browser ignores my css rule but the rule is not crossed.

[image]

[image]

We can see the width of the column is 142px even though the css rule tells the browser to apply only 65px.

The latest version of Chrome is installed, there is no active plugin and it was working in Firefox.

What might be the reasons for the browser overriding the width of a table column ?

Comment: Maybe your cache is full and it couldn't write the new width since you can't reproduce on other pcs

Comment: if website is live then share url , so we can check and analyse.

Comment: Can I see the selector and properties?

Comment: I tried to empty the cache. // I can't share the url because it's from a paid software that requires an account to log-in. // In the Styles tab, I just saw the rule that sets 65px and nothing else that affects the width property.